# Org-mode Table, No export Latex column

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-table

Is there a way to have a column of a table not export, specifically in latex? I want to have an extra column for personal notes but when I export I don't want the table there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641379/org-mode-tables-exclude-columns-from-export), I was able to get this to work by prepending

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{array}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
#+ATTR_LATEX: :align rrH
|Good column| another good column|column to hide in export|
| data      | data               | notes                  |
```

to the table. This creates a new column type `H` for a hidden column and then uses that type in the `align` attribute. So in the above example, it would hide the 3rd column.